# Openldap automatically assign attribute when user in group

Tags: openldap

Can Openldap automatically assign attribute,  or attribute value(text field) when user  added to group?
I'm trying to integrate lenovo IMM management with openldap infrastructure, and it need to add some string to any allowed user, for control access to system modules.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `memberOf` operational attribute can be automatically added and maintained by loading and suitable configuring the 'memberof' overlay.

Comment: Ok, But I need to add text value seem to:
IMMPermissions: IBMRBSPermissions=010000000000